# Closed-form for $\int_0^{\infty}(\sqrt[p]{x^p+1}-x)^p\,dx$, $p>\phi$; $\phi = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, closed-form

Let $p > 1$; what can be said about
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\left(\,\sqrt[p]{\,{x^{p} + 1}\,}
- x\right)^{p}\,\mathrm{d}x\ {\large ?}
$$
The condition $p > \phi$ is sufficient for convergence, since asymptotically the integrand is $\mbox{O}\left(x^{-p\left(p -1\right)\,\,\,}\right)$.

The case $p = 2$ is not bad
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)^2\,dx
\\[3mm] = &\
\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\!\left.%
\frac{2x^{3}}{3}- \frac{2x^{2}}{3} \sqrt{x^{2} + 1} -
\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x^{2} + 1} + x\right)\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ b}
\\[3mm] = &\
0 - \frac{-2}{3} = \frac{2}{3}.
\end{align}
The other antiderivatives seemed to involve the hypergeometric function, so the FTC didn't really pan out, and I couldn't reduce it to a beta integral or some such to evaluate it by hand
( though I did run the first few
$p \in \mathbb{N}$ through Wolfram Alpha; no clear pattern ).

Maybe there's a clever transformation I'm missing that would make this problem tractable.

Comment: Using the substitution $\frac{\sqrt[p]{1+x^p}}{x}=\frac{1}{t}$ there is: $$\int_0^\infty  \left(\sqrt[p]{1+x^p}-x\right)^pdx=\int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^p}{(1-t^p)^{\frac{2p+1}{p}}}dt$$ So atleast when $p \in \mathbb N$ you can get a closed form by using the binomial formula, followed by the Beta function.

Comment: I am ready to bet that the integral is very quickly  $\sim \frac 1 {p+1}$

Comment: For $p>2$, if we don't raise to the $p^{th}$ power we have $\int_0^{\infty } \left(\left(x^p+1\right)^{1/p}-x\right) \,
   dx=\frac{2^{-\frac{p+2}{p}} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p}\right) \Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}.$